# Integer solutions of the following question:

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

How many integer solutions are there in this equation:

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 63, \quad x_i \ge 0, \quad x_2 ≥10$$

I got $C(56,3)$.

Is that correct?

Comment: Can you explain how you get $C(56,3)$?

Answer (score 2):

Give $10$ immediately to $x_2$ (maybe more later) leaving $k=63-10=53$ to be distributed. Now it is a standard $\binom{n+k-1}k$ problem, with $n=5$. The answer is $\binom{57}{53}=\binom{57}4=395010$.

Comment: I think you forgot a 4 somewhere when you did 63-10=53 because the other 4 variables are >=0 which affects the problem

Comment: no its correct when you give 10 things to $x_2$ 53 things left. Now forget that you gave anything to $x_2$ you have five variables and 53 things to distribute such that $x_i>=0$. For this Marc's answer is correct

Comment: so it's C(57,4) then?

Comment: yes it is C(57,4)

Answer (score 0):

No, give 10 things to $x_2$ 53 things left , any 5 of them can get any value so answer is
$\frac{57!}{4!53!}$. Basically formula for distribution of $n$ identical things in $r$ distinct bins where each bin can get any number of things is $\frac{(n+r-1)!}{n!(r-1)!}$

Comment: Ok I see what you did there!

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $y_1 = x_1 + 1, y_2 = x_2 - 9, y_3 = x_3 + 1, y_4 = x_4 + 1, y_5 = x_5 + 1$.  This yields the equivalent problem
$$
(y_1 - 1) + (y_2 + 9) + (y_3 - 1) + (y_4 - 1) + (y_5 - 1) = 63; y_i \ge 1
$$
i.e.
$$
y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + \cdots + y_5 = 58
$$
By a classic stars-and-bars argument (writing $58$ in unary) the answer is then
$$
{58 - 1 \choose 5 - 1} = {57 \choose 4}.
$$